ShapeNet VAE KL Divergence issues
I am trying to train a VAE on shapenet but I can't seem to make it work. Any help or ideas would be highly appreciated. Now the problem is whenever I apply the KL divergence loss the network seems to get stuck with having a high KL divergence and high reconstruction loss. Even though without the KL divergence (plain auto encoder) the reconstructions are almost perfect.
Problem Setup:
Input: 64^3 TSDFs of shapenet
For now, I am just trying with the chair category of around (6.5k chairs)
Ouput: 64^3 TSDF- reconstruction
Network Architecture: I am mostly using the same architecture as in AutoSDF, which is a fully 3D convolutional encoder and decoder to output the final TSDF matrix. I tried with various latent space sizes but none seems to work.
KL divergence loss function:
loss = -0.5 * torch.sum(1 + logvar.flatten(1) - mu.flatten(1).pow(2) -
                                    logvar.flatten(1).exp(), dim=1)
loss = torch.mean(loss, dim=0)

where mu and logvar are the 3D outputs of the encoder (tried with different latent space sizes as explained below).
List of experiment settings

Latent spaces of (2*8*8*8), (4*8*8*8*8), (8*8*8*8*8) (16*8*8*8*8) , (32*8*8*8) and (64*8*8*8): None of them seemed to work in the VAE setting, but (16*8*8*8*8) , (32*8*8*8) and (64*8*8*8) worked well in the regular AE setting.
Added linear layers to the final output to obtain mu and logvar with 512 dimensionality in one experiment and 1024 in another -> made things worse
Followed all suggestions in this thread. Including "KL cost annealing" and "cyclic annealing".
Tried to normalize the KL loss weighting by the dimensionality of the latent space
Several combinations of reconstruction weighting and KL divergence weighting
Used the sum reduction instead of mean to get a higher priority for the reconstruction loss

None of the above seems to work an I have done a fair bit of research now, but I have no idea what to do next so I would appreciate any help or discussion.
